# Identifying Indentation Error w/ Closing Brackets }

Tags: java, netbeans, formatting

I'm attempting to submit my code for automatic review and I'm getting failures that I don't quite understand. I am using Netbeans with TMC for submission in MOOC.fi. The two errors I am getting specifically are:

1. `Line 15: '}' should be on the same line.`
2. `Line 18: '}' should be on the same line.`

This is the code in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckYourIndentation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Give a number: ");
        int first = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Give another number: ");
        int second = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        if (first == second) {
            System.out.println("Same!"); 
        }
        else if (first > second) {
            System.out.println("The first was larger than the second!"); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The second was larger than the first!");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FcvmxAai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put `else if` and `else` on the same line as the final brackets of the previous block. In other words, this was the correct final result: https://pastebin.com/CchVXq2M

```
if (first == second) {
    System.out.println("Same!"); 
} else if (first > second) {
    System.out.println("The first was larger than the second!"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("The second was larger than the first!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you see this problem but I test your code with my netbeans IDE and it works normally